# pgsql -Showing top 10 products's sales and other products as 'others' and its sum of sales

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called "products" where it has 100 records with sales details. My requirement is so simple that I was not able to do it.

I need to show the top 10 product names with sales and other product names as "others" and its sales. so totally my o/p will be 11 rows. 11-th row should be others and sum of sales of all remaining products. Can anyone give me the logic?

O/p should be like this,

```
      Name          sales
     ------         ----- 
1    colgate        9000
2    pepsodent      8000
3    closeup        7000
4    brittal        6000
5    ariies         5000
6    babool         4000
7    imami          3000
8    nepolop        2500
9    lactoteeth     2000
10   menwhite       1500
11   Others         6000 (sum of sales of remaining 90 products)
```

here is my sql query,

```
select case when rank<11 then prod_cat else 'Others' END as prod_cat,
total_sales,ID,rank from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (sum(i.grandtotal)) desc) as rank,pc.name as prod_cat,sum(i.grandtotal) as total_sales, pc.m_product_category_id as ID`enter code here`
from adempiere.c_invoice i join adempiere.c_invoiceline il on il.c_invoice_id=i.c_invoice_id join adempiere.m_product p on p.m_product_id=il.m_product_id join adempiere.m_product_category pc on pc.m_product_category_id=p.m_product_category_id
where extract(year from i.dateacct)=extract(year from now())
group by  pc.m_product_category_id) innersql
order by  total_sales desc
```

o/p what i got is,

```
prod_cat   total_sales     id           rank
--------   -----------     ---          ----
BSHIRT     4511697.63      460000015     1
BT-SHIRT   2725167.03      460000016     2
SHIRT      2630471.56      1000003       3
BJEAN      1793514.07      460000005     4
JEAN       1115402.90      1000004       5
GT-SHIRT   1079596.33      460000062     6
T SHIRT     446238.60      1000006       7
PANT        405189.00      1000005       8
GDRESS      396789.02      460000059     9
BTROUSER    393739.48      460000017    10
Others      164849.41      1000009      11
Others      156677.00      1000008      12
Others      146678.00      1000007      13
```

Comment: So, you can figure out how to get the first 10 rows?

Comment: yes i can figure out first 10 rows by ordering sales to descending

Comment: i think this might help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420797/tsql-select-top-10-display-the-rest-as-other)

Comment: I guess what I was getting at was 'can you show us the query for that?'

Comment: @OferP Does Postgres play nicely with other dialects?

Comment: So if you know how to get the top 10 why not a simple UNION for the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @e4c5 suggests, use UNION:

```
select id, prod_cat, sum(total_sales) as total_sales
with
  totals as (
    select --pc.m_product_category_id as id,
           pc.name as prod_cat,
           sum(i.grandtotal) as total_sales,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (order by sum(i.grandtotal) desc) as rank
    from adempiere.c_invoice i
    join adempiere.c_invoiceline il on (il.c_invoice_id=i.c_invoice_id)
    join adempiere.m_product p on (p.m_product_id=il.m_product_id)
    join adempiere.m_product_category pc on (pc.m_product_category_id=p.m_product_category_id)
    where i.dateacct >= date_trunc('year', now()) and i.dateacct < date_trunc('year', now()) + interval '1' year
    group by pc.m_product_category_id, pc.name
    ),
  rankedothers as (
    select prod_cat, total_sales, rank
    from totals where rank <= 10
    union
    select 'Others', sum(total_sales), 11
    from totals where rank > 10
    )
select prod_cat, total_sales
from ranked_others
order by rank
```

Also, I recommend using [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) conditions like the one above, which is slightly more complicated than the one you implemented, but generally worth the extra effort.

Comment: thanks for your support. i got my requirement but still i need to get the 'others' as last record instead of middle...is it possible ?